# throw new IllegalOperationException Java

Tags: java, exception, operation

I am trying to throw a new IllegalOperationException but eclipse says that it can not be resolved to a type when all of my other exceptions are working just fine. Is there something else I need to do for this to work?

Comment: No type resolved is no type resolved. This doesn't change, ever. Find out what is *supposed* to provide the type (and reference/import/qualify it), or correct the [mis]type to what is *really* supposed to be.

Comment: `IllegalOperationException` does not exist in the JDK. However, there is a similar [`UnsupportedOperationException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/UnsupportedOperationException.html)

Answer (score 6):

`IllegalOperationException` is not a part of [java.lang](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/package-summary.html). Something similar that might work for you is `java.lang.IllegalStateException` which is defined as follows:

> Signals that a method has been invoked at an illegal or inappropriate
>   time. In other words, the Java environment or Java application is not
>   in an appropriate state for the requested operation.

[Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalStateException.html).

Answer (score 0):

Since,you're trying to throw a new Exception i.e. a custom exception.. You need to create a separate class for that which must be a sub-class to either Throwable or Exception. And then you can throw it whenever the required condition is not satisfied. If I'm not wrong then, this might be the solution to your bug.